# TabBarController with ScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I want to make something like instagram, tabview with scroll views
Tried doing it like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhhW3xqhCzg) but it didnt work (maybe because it has to be a different way with tabviews)
can somebody give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Keep in mind that tableView is a child of scrollView. All you need to do in order to create an app like Instagram is fetching different kind of CustomTableViewCells. For instance the first Cell with the Insta Stories, should contain a CollectionView etc.